# Dreamhost Standalone Passenger with Capistrano not recognizing current/public web directory

Tags: capistrano, passenger, dreamhost

I have just set up a VPS at Dreamhost. Installing my first Ruby on Rails application went fine using a clone of a github account to get the code. I did the standalone install of Passenger because I need the latest versions of Ruby and Rails (see http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RVM).

Now I'm setting up my second RoR app which uses Capistrano, which means the web directory needs to be  current/public rather than /public. I've been able to get the code deployed using Capistrano, but I keep getting errors when trying to start Passenger:

```
2012/09/29 20:34:29 [error] 10475#0: *4 "/home/<user>/<domain>/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
```

I've verified in the Dreamhost control panel that the web directory is set correctly (mydomain.com/current/public) but obviously it's not recognizing that.

Any suggestions where to look for the problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work. The problem was that I needed to start Passenger Standalone in the "current" directory, not the root directory of the application. Hope this helps someone else struggling with a similar setup.